Why does using Thunderbird’s message filter mark some mails automatically as read?
I implemented message filters on a few of my inboxes. Mostly where I move mails from a specific sender to a subfolder of the same inbox. This works mostly fine but for one of my mail adresses when doing so the mail gets automatically marked as read.
I tried adding a "Mark as unread" filter to my message filter but this doesn't seem to work.
This might be related to this unanswered issue. Moving an unread message maually seem to result in similar results.
